# How does one say "one bad apple..." in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

The idiom "one bad apple spoils the (whole) bunch", or the alternate form "one bad apple spoils the barrel", means that a bad person, policy, etc, can ruin everything around it. Is there a way to express this in Esperanto?

Answer (score 8):

There is this [proverb](http://www.robkeetlaer.nl/esperanto/proverbaro/proverbo_002512.htm) in Zamenhof’s collection of proverbs:

> Unu ovo malbona tutan manĝon difektas

Roughly translated that is:

> One bad egg spoils a whole meal

Assuming people know their *proverbaro* off by heart, it might work to call the person just *malbona ovo*. Presumably there is some parent saying that English has borrowed as well because of course it’s quite common to call someone a “bad egg” in English too.

The linked page also suggests the following related sayings which seem to have more or less the same meaning:

> Plena glaso da vino, sed kun guto da veneno
>
> Unu fava ŝafo tutan ŝafaron infektas

However it’s probably more of a stretch to call the person a *guto de veneno* or a *fava ŝafo*.

Comment: In Italian, we say _uova marce_ (_rotten eggs_) when referring to a person. (I don't understand why we use the plural, though.) I would understand _ovo malbona_ to mean the same.

Comment: And if they don't know their *proverbaro* by heart, we can shame them into reading more -- or at least use *malbona ovo* as a teachable moment to point out Esperanto literature.